# Scaling the entirely content of a container based on the viewport width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the following up with a text inside a container:
[Desired behavior animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mopCk.gif)

But unfortunately, that's what I'm getting:
[My approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBbNG.gif)

Here's the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .container {
            max-width: 1920px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: clamp(12px, 10vw, 142px);
            text-transform: uppercase;
            align-items: center;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .title:last-child{
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="title">Get in touch</h2>
            <h2 class="title">Know about me</h2>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set height of your container using `vw` as well as width of your element consider

```
height : 20vw;
```

It will work as you want, let me know if otherwise

Comment: I've tried it but it hasn't worked as expected behavior:
_[code's screenshot] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAHWK.png)_

I've tried width font size: clamp(14px, 20vw, 140px) or without the element width and nothing.

Comment: I used the vw inside if a fiddle and it worked just like your desired demo, here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/mahdiar_mansouri/qft73rvc/

Comment: Ouh yeah! Your code seems to work as I wanted. You didn't mention anything about the width of the container itself it the firt answer, but thank you so much!

Comment: yea I didn't realize it does not have ```width```  ,  you're welcome, Good Luck